Integrating Together i.i.d. Random Variables
Suppose $Q$ is an instantaneous flow rate of some fluid in a pipe. $Q$ is a normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^{2}$.
Now suppose that I wanted to know the volume of water was dispensed by the pipe in time $T$ (let's call this random variable $V_T$). What distribution does $V_T$ follow?
I feel like what I want to do is define a set of random variables $Q_t$:
$$Q_t \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2}),t \in [0,T]$$
And then integrate between $0$ and $T$.
$$ V_T = \int_{0}^{T} Q_t dt $$
The discrete sum of a set of normal i.i.d. variables is also normal with linearly scaling mean and variance, but this is obviously a continuous integral. Intuitively though I want to say the same result holds (i.e. $V_t \sim \mathcal{N}(T\mu,\,T\sigma^{2})$), and in the context of the problem this sounds like a reasonable answer but I can't quite tie a proof together that I'm happy with. (I can only come up with some sum/limit manipulation of questionable validity).
Also if $Q$ followed some other distribution, is there an integral analogue of the central limit theorem I can use?

Update - To show where I'm at with the dodgy sum computations;
From the definition of the integral:
$$ V_T = \lim_{h\to0} (\sum_{t=1}^{T/h} (Q_t h)) $$
$$ = \lim_{h\to0} h (\sum_{t=1}^{T/h} Q_t) $$
$$ = \lim_{h\to0} hA $$
where $A \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu\frac{T}{h},\,\sigma^{2}\frac{T}{h})$.
$$ = \lim_{h\to0} B $$
where $B \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu\frac{T}{h}h,\,\sigma^{2}\frac{T}{h}h^2)$.
The above is just using standard results of adding normal variables and linear transformations. Then taking limits...
$$ V_t \sim \mathcal{N}(\lim_{h\to0} T\mu,\,\lim_{h\to0} Th\sigma^{2}) $$
$$ V_t \sim \mathcal{N}(T\mu, 0) $$
The mean sounds about right but $0$ variance? Doesn't add up (though I acknowledge that my original guess can't be right as it doesn't have the correct units).

You may want to use Brownian motion models.

Note that I am not an expert in this area, so take my comment with its due risk. The central limit theorem and also your idea of approximating the continuous distribution with the analogous discrete distribution may need to be delved into deeper, since $Q_{t}$ collection is not a set of i.i.d. distributions (I am emphasizing on independence, to be clear). Since your instantaneous flow rate is the same random variable that you are modeling as a sum, the fact that they are dependent could matter. I am not saying that your conclusions or intuition is/are wrong due to this.
